# A/B test with an Angular app [Google Optimize]

Tags: javascript, angular, google-website-optimizer

I am trying to run an A/B-test in Google Optimize on a simple 3-step form written in Angular.

The results for the next step are calculations based on the input variables in previous steps, and the HTML is output through the Angular app.

So the page renders with the variables first, then the new HTML/CSS renders for the A/B-test - the problem is that I can't access the output variables that change.

Would it be possible to somehow grab these variables when they are created dynamically and then display them in the new version? (all without altering the original Angular app - I don't have access to that)

Comment: is this [tag:angular] (2.x) or [tag:angularjs] (1.x)?  These **are not** the same framework, and don't even operate similarly.

Comment: sorry for the confusion in the tagging, the framework in question is angular and **NOT** angularjs.